# Invalid string in json text while trying to send json object to a controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I am trying to send json object from javascript to rails controller and i keep getting this error

```
  MultiJson::DecodeError (lexical error: invalid string in json text.
                                   tag=hello
                 (right here) ------^
```

I am using yajl,rails 3.1,jquery 1.6.

**Yajl setup**
   *in gemfile*
     gem 'yajl-ruby'

*config/application.rb*

```
 require 'yajl/json_gem'
```

**My code**

*ajax function*

```
    var myobj={"tag":"hello"};
    $.ajax({
    url: 'ips/create',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    accept: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data:$.param(myobj),

    success: function(res) {
        if (res.ImportResponse !== void 0) {
            console.log('Success: ' + res);
        } else if (res.Fault !== void 0) {
            console.log('Fault: ' + res);
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        console.error('error!!!!');
    }
   });

*In controller*

     parser = Yajl::Parser.new
     hash = parser.parse(request.body.read)
```

Comment: well, you set your contentType to json and instead sent a param string. That error makes complete sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be sending json data with that request, not a param string.

```
...
data: JSON.stringify(myobj),
...
```

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone , now i just get missing template erreor